# php regex - cookie name

Tags: php, regex, cookies

i need help again.
I have to code a function that gets me the cookie. but i only knows part of the cookie name. I got a JavaScript-Function that's working very well:

```
function readCookie(cookiePart){            
            var results = document.cookie.match(cookiePart + '(.*)=(.*?)(;|$)');            
            if(results){
                var result = results[0].replace(cookiePart,''); 
                var cookie= result.split("="); 
                return(cookie[0])           
            }else{
                return null
            }
        }           
        alert(readCookie("cookie_"));
```

I try to code the same for PHP. But still stuck:

```
$cookie_name = "cookie_";   
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["$cookie_name" . "/^*$/"])) {
        echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
    } else {
        echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";       
    }
```

i think i do the regex part wrong. maybe you can help me where to add it? i tried on the varaiablename when define or match, but nothing works.

thx for any hint my friends!

Comment: added a dot in your pattern  /^.*$/ dot matches any characters and the star matchs characters 0 or more times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem

The thing is, that in JavaScript you used a method `.match()` for regexp, but you didn't use anything for regexp in PHP.

And you cannot that easily match keys, you can only do this when iterating over entire array.

But you don't have to use regexp to achieve what you need.

### Solution

I recommend this:

```
$set = false;
$cookie_name = 'cookie_';
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
    if (stripos($name,$cookie_name) === 0) {
        echo "Cookie named '$name' is set with value '$value'!";
        $set = true;
    }
}
if (!$set) {
    echo 'No cookie found :(';
}
```

Will list all valid cookies (having names beginning with "cookie_"), or display sad message.

And I think that if you can achieve something relatively easy without regex, you should.

### If you need to use cookie names afterwards

Use this modified code:

```
$cookie_name = 'cookie_';
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
    if (stripos($name,$cookie_name) === 0) {
        $cookies[] = $name;
    }
}
```

And you have now table `$cookies` that contains names of every valid cookie set. If you need only part that's after `_` then use this line instead:

```
$cookies[] = str_replace('cookie_','',$name);
```

Comment: ok thanks for your explanation! i will check this. why you said i should not use regex...whats the reason behind? perfomance?

Comment: Yes. Regex (`preg_match`, `preg_replace`) is always more heavy on performance than other string functions like `stripos()`, `stristr()` or `str_replace()`. Other reason is that regex is complicated and easy to generate errors when you are not good with it. Also, your case is as simply as "starts with 'cookie_' and then has anything", so I recommend using `stripos()` to check if cookie name contains `cookie_` part at the very beginning.

Comment: ok thx, i played a lil arround with it and i have to say: nice solution! thx for your great explanation!!! HQ-user!

Answer (score -1):

```
function keyLike(array $arr, $like)
{
    foreach (array_keys($arr) as $k) {
        if (preg_match($like, $k)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
...
if (keyLike($_COOKIE, '/^cookie_.+/')) { ...
```

Comment: that's great! exactly what i was looking for! thx and i will mark as correct in 2 minutes :)

Comment: what if i need the part after the "_"...the part im not knowing?